# Regular expression not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I´m trying to get the email from and cc from a forwarded email, when the body looks like this:

```
$body = '-------
Begin forwarded message:


From: Sarah Johnson <blabla@gmail.com>

Subject: email subject

Date: February 22, 2013 3:48:12 AM

To: Email Recipient <thatwouldbe@yayyy.com>

Cc: Ralph Johnson <johnson@gmail.com>


Hi,


hello, thank you and goodbye!

 blabla@gmail.com'
```

Now, when I do the following:

```
$body = strtolower($body);
$pattern = '#from: \D*\S([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\S#';
if (preg_match($pattern, $body, $arr_matches)) {
     echo htmlentities($arr_matches[0]);
     die();
}
```

I correctly get:

```
from: sarah johnson <blabla@gmail.com>
```

Now, why does the cc don't work? I do something very similar, only changing from to cc:

```
$body = strtolower($body);
$pattern = '#cc: \D*\S([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\S#';
if (preg_match($pattern, $body, $arr_matches)) {
     echo htmlentities($arr_matches[0]);
     die();
}
```

and I get:

```
cc: ralph johnson <johnson@gmail.com> hi, hello, thank you and goodbye! blabla@gmail.com
```

If I remove the email from the original body footer (removing blabla@gmail.com) then I correctly get:

```
cc: ralph johnson <johnson@gmail.com>
```

It looks like that email is affecting the regular expression. But how, and why doesn't it affect it in the from? How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me: http://regex101.com/r/eQ6iS8 On second look, I see some problems. If you change the last email address to From it fails the way you're currently seeing. The Regex is being too greedy. I'll see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `\D*` matches too much, i.e. it is also matching newline characters. I would be more restrictive here. Why do you use `\D`(not a Digit) at all?

With e.g. `[^@]*` it is working

```
cc: [^@]*\S([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\S
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33u11).

This way, you are sure that this first part is not matching beyond the email address.

This `\D` is also the reason, it is working for the first, the "From" case. There are digits in the "Date" row, therefore it does not match over this row.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$body = '-------
Begin forwarded message:


From: Sarah Johnson <blabla@gmail.com>

Subject: email subject

Date: February 22, 2013 3:48:12 AM

To: Email Recipient <thatwouldbe@yayyy.com>

Cc: Ralph Johnson <johnson@gmail.com>


Hi,


hello, thank you and goodbye!

 blabla@gmail.com';

$pattern = '#(?:from|Cc):\s+[^<>]+<([^@]+@[^>\s]+)>#is';
preg_match_all($pattern, $body, $arr_matches);
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($arr_matches, 1)) . '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => From: Sarah Johnson <blabla@gmail.com>
            [1] => Cc: Ralph Johnson <johnson@gmail.com>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla@gmail.com
            [1] => johnson@gmail.com
        )

)

$arr_matches[1][0] - "From" email
$arr_matches[1][1] - "Cc" email
```